# Django, Set some values of a form field in the model

Tags: django, forms, django-models

It's a bit odd but I would like to define some properties of a form field like its widget or class from the model definition. I know it is easy from the form but I'd like to know if it's possible from the model. I'm not sure but I think I remember having seen something like that some day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, you can create your own subclasses of model fields and redefine their `formfield` method to add the properties you want but it might not be worth the effors as you'll be overriding . That's hour call, however.

Anyway, in case you decide to try this, make sure to follow these two sections from the documentation:
[ModelForms and custom fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-model-fields/#modelforms-and-custom-fields)
and
[Specifying the form field for a model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field) as the default implementation of `Field.formfield` does some important stuff you generally don't want to omit.